# Verify signature generated online with public key

Tags: x509certificate, electronic-signature

I work with  ([browser token signing](https://github.com/open-eid/browser-token-signing) ) to sign a text with x509 certificate. I'd like to verify that the Generated signature is valid or not.
is there any tools to verify the Generated signature online or other way????

[test signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT7nB.png)

Comment: You can use [WebCryptographyApi 's verify method](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#SubtleCrypto-method-verify) to verify a signature in the browser using the public key. You need also to extract the public key from the x509certificate. To do this use a javascript library like forge (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509). You can find detailed info for these steps in this site

Comment: @pedrofb how to use this method?

Comment: First, import key in spki format https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---importkey Second, verify the signature with https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---verify. Use forge to extract the public key as raw data from x509. I can't provide you a full example because there are several parts involved. You may want to try it, and come back with the problems so the community could help you with a localized issue